# Can not submit confirmation text to fabric console confirm, see ^M instead

Tags: python, console, fabric

I have the following Fabric task:

```
@task
def production():
    if not console.confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed on production?', default=False):
            utils.abort('Production operation aborted.')
    stage_set('production')
```

Now, when I try to deploy production I see in terminal:

```
$ fab production deploy
Are you sure you want to proceed on production? [y/N] yes^M
```

I type yes, hit Enter and "^M" pops up instead of submitting my text. The more Enters I hit the more "^M"s I see.

"Ctrl+C" results in "^C" on the screen and only hitting it several times terminates the input.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Apparently this was an iTerm app issue.